# confint vs intervals for gls (nlme package) models

Tags: r, linear-regression, confidence-interval, nlme, t-test

There are two methods available to estimate confidence intervals for a `gls` model in R: using function `confint` and function `intervals`. The results are not the same and I want to know what are the causes of the differences and which one is the preferred to use for a `gls` (and for `lme` as well) models.

I will use the `cats` data set for this example. I will use four different approaches to estimate the mean difference (MD) of `Hwt` between `sex`:

- t-test (heterogeneous variance)
- Linear model, using `lm` (homogeneous variance)
- Linear model, using `gls` (homogeneous variance)
- Heteroscedastic linear model, using `gls` (heterogeneous variance)

for the `gls` approaches `confint` and `intervals` are available for calculating confidence intervals.
Here is the code:

```r
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse)
p_load(MASS)
p_load(nlme)

set.seed(150)

cats%>%ggplot(aes(x=Sex,y=Hwt))+
  geom_boxplot()+theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
###different approaches for the same mean difference estimation
cats_ttest<-t.test(Hwt~Sex,data=cats)
cats$Sex<-relevel(cats$Sex,ref="M")
cats_lm<-lm(Hwt~Sex,data=cats)
cats_gls_hom<-gls(Hwt~Sex,data=cats)
cats_gls_het<-gls(Hwt~Sex,weights=varIdent(form=~1|Sex),data=cats)

###store estimations and CI's from different approaches
a<-rbind(confint(cats_lm),confint(cats_gls_hom),confint(cats_gls_het),
         intervals(cats_gls_hom,which = "coef")$coef[,c(1,3)],
         intervals(cats_gls_het,which = "coef")$coef[,c(1,3)]) %>% data.frame%>% {cbind(par=rownames(.),.)}
a$par<-a$par %>% str_remove_all("X.|.1|.2|.3|.4")
a$par<-factor(a$par,levels =c("Intercept.","SexF"),
              labels =c("Intercept.","SexF") )

a$est<-c(rep(cats_lm %>% coef,3),
         cats_gls_hom %>% coef,cats_gls_het %>% coef
         )
a$mod<-c(rep("cats_lm_ci",2),rep("cats_gls_hom_ci",2),rep("cats_gls_het_ci",2),
         rep("cats_gls_hom_int",2),rep("cats_gls_het_int",2)
         )
colnames(a)[2:3]<-c("LCI","UCI")
a<-rbind(data.frame(par="SexF",LCI=cats_ttest$conf.int[1],
                    UCI=cats_ttest$conf.int[2],est=cats_ttest$estimate[1]-cats_ttest$estimate[2],
                    mod="ttest"),a)
a$mod<-factor(a$mod,levels =c("ttest","cats_lm_ci","cats_gls_hom_ci","cats_gls_het_ci","cats_gls_hom_int","cats_gls_het_int"))
a$diff<-a$UCI-a$LCI
rownames(a)<-NULL

###results
a[order(a$par,a$diff),]
#>           par       LCI       UCI       est              mod      diff
#> 4  Intercept. 10.879181 11.766179 11.322680  cats_gls_hom_ci 0.8869980
#> 2  Intercept. 10.875369 11.769992 11.322680       cats_lm_ci 0.8946223
#> 8  Intercept. 10.875369 11.769992 11.322680 cats_gls_hom_int 0.8946223
#> 6  Intercept. 10.816754 11.828606 11.322680  cats_gls_het_ci 1.0118521
#> 10 Intercept. 10.812406 11.832955 11.322680 cats_gls_het_int 1.0205495
#> 7        SexF -2.758218 -1.482888 -2.120553  cats_gls_het_ci 1.2753295
#> 11       SexF -2.763699 -1.477407 -2.120553 cats_gls_het_int 1.2862917
#> 1        SexF -2.763753 -1.477352 -2.120553            ttest 1.2864011
#> 5        SexF -2.896844 -1.344261 -2.120553  cats_gls_hom_ci 1.5525835
#> 3        SexF -2.903517 -1.337588 -2.120553       cats_lm_ci 1.5659288
#> 9        SexF -2.903517 -1.337588 -2.120553 cats_gls_hom_int 1.5659288

a %>% ggplot(aes(x=par,y=est,color=mod,group=mod))+geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.5))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=LCI, ymax=UCI), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(0.5))+theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As you can see, there are mild differences in CI amplitudes from the different methods,and as expected, the methods which accounts for differences in variances produced the narrowest CI for the mean differences (parameter `SexF` in dataframe `a`).

So, why are two methods available to estimate confidence intervals for `gls` models, what are the differences between them and which one is the preferred one for this kind of models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** use `intervals()`, it gives you CIs based on a Student-t rather than a Normal sampling distribution.

If you look at `methods(class = "gls")` you'll see that `confint()` *is not listed*.  That means that when you call `confint(gls_fit)`, R falls back to the default `confint` method. If we look at the code for `stats::confint.default` you'll see `fac <- qnorm(a); ...; ci[] <- cf[parm] + ses %o% fac`. In other words, `confint.default` is constructing CIs based on a Normal distribution.

In contrast, `nlme:::intervals.gls` uses

```r
 len <- -qt((1 - level)/2, dims$N - dims$p) * sqrt(diag(object$varBeta))
```

— i.e., an interval based on a t-distribution.

It makes very little difference in this case (CI interval width of 1.55 vs 1.56).

For what it's worth, you can streamline this kind of comparison a little bit using `broom`/`broom.mixed` (although this does **not** include the `confint.default` option for `gls`!)

```r
library(broom)
library(broom.mixed)
options(pillar.sigfig = 7)
(tibble::lst(cats_ttest, cats_lm, cats_gls_hom, cats_gls_het)
    |> map_dfr(tidy, .id = "model", conf.int = TRUE)
    ## t-test doesn't have a "term" element
    |> mutate(across(term, ~ifelse(is.na(.), "SexF", term)))
    |> select(model, term, estimate, lwr = conf.low, upr = conf.high)
    |> mutate(width = upr - lwr)
    |> arrange(term)
)
```

As a general rule, you should use the *most* specific method available — this usually happens automatically, it's sort of an accident that `confint()` works for `gls` objects (partly because the `nlme` package predates R itself, so doesn't follow all of its conventions ...)

Comment: as a side question, why CI on intercept is wider on model cats_gls_het_int vs cats_gls_hom_int while the CI on the mean difference is wider in cats_gls_hom_int?

Comment: not immediately obvious to me, ask on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ... ?